# how to use virtualbox inside docker

Tags: virtualbox, docker

I want to install virtualbox inside a docker container.

When I run [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/jencryzthers/vboxinsidedocker/):

```
docker run -v /dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv --name=vbox jencryzthers/vboxinsidedocker
```

I am expecting the virtualbox to run, but nothing shows up. What am I missing?
(Yes, I did install  install and load the Virtualbox driver on the
host )

Comment: Have you checked all applicable log files for these systems and apps you are using here? See if you can enabled logging or poke thru some logs and see if that provides any clue. Perhaps look over running processes before and then after running the command and take note of differences.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can run virtualbox in docker containers. There are low level kernel compatibility issues.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, I think instead of an answer this should written in Comments!